# How do I capture this R Shiny expandable reactive user input matrix as another reactive object for further manipulation?

Tags: r, matrix, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In the below example R Shiny code, there are two types of input matrixes. The first (rendered at the top in the sidebar panel and generated by function `matInputBase()`) captures user input variables "Y" and applies them over a time window "W". This top matrix is then split into 2 expandable matrixes (generated by function `matInputFlex()`), where the user can optionally change variables Y at times "X". I stripped out all the calculations code and leave only the user input matrixes. User input matrixes are generated by package `shinyMatrix`.

How do I capture as a reactive object these two matrixes generated by `matInputFlex()`, and for the sake of example, render them in the main panel as a table?

I need to capture that object for download/upload functionality, as well as to make subsequent calculations easier. The data is meant to flow from `matInputBase()` to `matInputFlex()` to this to-be-built reactive object that I would like to play around with. Flow is downstream, whereby inputs into `matInputBase()` flow to `matInputFlex()`, but they never flow from `matInputFlex()` to `matInputBase()`. The below illustration helps explain.

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

matInputBase <- function(name){
  matrixInput(name, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("Var_1","Var_2"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")
}

matInputFlex <- function(name, x, y) {
  matrixInput(name,
              value = matrix(c(x, y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = FALSE),
              cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 0, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE), 
              class = "numeric")
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput('periods', 'Time window (W):', min = 1, max = 20, value = 20),
    h5(strong("Var (Y) over time window:")),
    matInputBase("base_input"),
    actionButton('resetVectorBtn', 'Reset'),
    uiOutput("Vectors")
  ), 
  mainPanel(h5("Show the 2 adjustable matrixes here as DF...")) # show new object that copies adjustable
) 

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  periods <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input <- reactive(input$base_input)

  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetVectorBtn
    tagList(
      h5(strong("Adjust Var_1 (Y) at time X:")),
      matInputFlex("var_1_vector_input", input$periods, input$base_input[1, 1]),
      h5(strong("Adjust Var_2 (Y) at time X:")),
      matInputFlex("var_2_vector_input", input$periods, input$base_input[2, 1])
    )
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Why do `input$var_1_vector_input` and `input$var_2_vector_input` not meet your needs?  From the package documentation - "You can access the input via the ‘input$inputId‘ in the server function of the shiny application. The value will always be a matrix and contain values of class ‘class‘".

Comment: `input$var_1_vector_input` is of class matrix, ready to be printed into a table or manipulated as desired. It's also already reactive as it's an input. I don't see a need to modify your functions, just access the cells of the matrices as any other matrix `input$var_1_vector_input[2, 1]` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the relevant table outputs in your UI:

```r
mainPanel(
    h5("Matrix 1"),
    tableOutput("m1"),
    h5("Matrix 2"),
    tableOutput("m2")
)
```

And then in your server function update those when the input changes. As noted in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77858654/how-do-i-capture-this-r-shiny-expandable-reactive-user-input-matrix-as-another-r/77858807?noredirect=1#comment137259721_77858654) by Limey, the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyMatrix/readme/README.html) state:

> You can access the value from the matrix input using input$inputId in your server function. The result will always be a matrix of the class defined in matrixInput.

```r
output$m1 <- renderTable(input$var_1_vector_input)
output$m2 <- renderTable(input$var_2_vector_input)
```

[image]

##### Full app code

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

matInputBase <- function(name) {
    matrixInput(name,
        value = matrix(c(0.2), 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("Var_1", "Var_2"), NULL)),
        rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
        cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
        class = "numeric"
    )
}

matInputFlex <- function(name, x, y) {
    matrixInput(name,
        value = matrix(c(x, y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y"))),
        rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = FALSE),
        cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 0, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
        class = "numeric"
    )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("periods", "Time window (W):", min = 1, max = 20, value = 20),
        h5(strong("Var (Y) over time window:")),
        matInputBase("base_input"),
        actionButton("resetVectorBtn", "Reset"),
        uiOutput("Vectors")
    ),
    mainPanel(
        h5("Matrix 1"),
        tableOutput("m1"),
        h5("Matrix 2"),
        tableOutput("m2")
    ) # show new object that copies adjustable
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    periods <- reactive(input$periods)
    base_input <- reactive(input$base_input)

    output$Vectors <- renderUI({
        input$resetVectorBtn
        tagList(
            h5(strong("Adjust Var_1 (Y) at time X:")),
            matInputFlex("var_1_vector_input", input$periods, input$base_input[1, 1]),
            h5(strong("Adjust Var_2 (Y) at time X:")),
            matInputFlex("var_2_vector_input", input$periods, input$base_input[2, 1])
        )
    })

output$m1 <- renderTable(input$var_1_vector_input)
output$m2 <- renderTable(input$var_2_vector_input)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi, to simplify slightly to see how this works I changed from ´mat_df <- rbind(var1_m$mat, var2_m$mat)´ to simply ´mat_df <- reactive(var1_m$mat)´. When I insert more rows of data into the Var_1 expandable matrix using ´matInputFlex()´, I don't see the additional data appearing in the ´mat_df´ table. I'm trying to capture all components of the evolving expanding matrix, real-time and reactively. As coded try inputting into the Var_1 and Var_2 tables and you'll see that the rendered table remains static. How can that output table be as dynamic as the user inputs?

Comment: @Village.Idyot sorry I misunderstood your original question - it's actually much simpler. I have re-written the answer.